# Unable to detect delete button of soft keyboard in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to detect back or delete button of soft keyboard using below method. Its working perfectly in physical devices but its not working `emulator`. Emulator is able to detect all the key events(like enter button, number buttons) expect delete button. On pressing the delete button in emulator neither `onKeyDown()` nor `dispatchKeyEvent()` is called.  What can be the problem ?

**Purpose of doing this:**

I am trying to navigate to previous `EditText` fields if the user presses delete on the current empty `EditText` field. That is why I was relying on the `dispatchKeyEvent()` method.

I am using **Nexus 5X API 25 emulator**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            Log.e(TAG,keyCode)
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:hint="Name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image of the delete button:

[image]

Comment: That question is completely different from mine. My code is working fine in all real devices. But not in emulator. @NileshRathod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After understanding your requirement I found that `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` are not working on `Nexus 5 API 25` emulator but TextWatcher can serve your purpose if you really want to use `Nexus 5 API 25` emulator.

On `Nexus 5X API 26`, `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` are working fine. Of course `TextWatcher` is working as well.

Use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to detect change in text inside EditText and there you can check which key is pressed. Below is working code:

```
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
            if (after < count) {
                Log.d("DELETE_KEY_PRESSED", "beforeTextChanged: ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length()>0 && s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
                Log.d("ENTER_KEY_PRESSED", "onTextChanged: ");
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                Log.d("DELETE_KEY_PRESSED", "onTextChanged: ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

You can use TextWatcher to detect all the other key pressed as well.

By the way, for me [onKeyDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) and [onKeyUp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyUp(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) are also working fine on emulator. I am using below code:

```
//To detect DELETE KEY PRESS event there is no text in EditText
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
        Log.d("KEY_PRESSED - onKeyDown", "KEYCODE_DEL");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

//To detect DELETE KEY PRESS event there is no text in EditText
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
        Log.d("KEY_PRESSED - onKeyUp", "KEYCODE_DEL");
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

**NOTE: I am using Nexus 5X API 26 emulator**

Comment: i want to detect the delete button. i dont think that is possible with your method.

Comment: @XoXo did you try my method? How you can say without testing? It will work.

Comment: Problem with your implementation is its not detecting the delete button when the `EditText` is empty. I am trying to navigate to previous EditText fields if the user presses delete on the current empty `EditText` field. That is why I was relying on the `dispatchKeyEvent()` method.

Comment: @XoXo did you mention this requirement in question? How I will know that you want to achieve this? I will update answer

Comment: I will update my question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: which emulator did you use ? I am using Nexus API 25. Is there any setting that we have to turn to make it work ?

Comment: @XoXo updated my answer for how to checking using `TextWatcher` if `EditText` is empty. Also `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` are also working as expected. Check attached video

Comment: @XoXo I am using `Nexus 5X API 26` emulator.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it looks `Nexus API 25` has some issue.

Comment: Perfect! Might be a bug in API 25

Comment: @XoXo Never mind. For future, please provide as much as information you can provide while asking any question. It will help other to understand your problem faster and provide required solution. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yeah thank you so much for the answer and advice. I will make sure to put clear questions.